# Declare function associated with a variable

Tags: php, anonymous-function, buddypress

I have the following situation:

```
add_action( 'bp_setup_nav',  function() {
    bp_core_new_nav_item( array(
        'screen_function'         => 'redirect_user_to_author_page',
    ));
});

$redirect_user_to_author_page = function (){
    wp_redirect(home_url());
    exit;
};
```

In the parameter `screen_function`, I must declare the function below. If I put the variable name without the $, the function is not called. If I put in $, PHP accuses error:

> Undefined variable: redirect_user_to_author_page

How an anonymous function associated with a variable must be declared in the parameter?

According to the documentation:

> screen_function String | Optional | Default: FALSE | Name of function
>   to run when the navigation item is clicked.

Comment: try to reverse the order, putting the `$redirect_user_to_author_page ... `before the `add_action`

Comment: @VincentG Same error: undefined variable.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't expect a function called `redirect_user_to_author_page` instead of a closure?

Comment: It expects a function called `redirect_user_to_author_page`, **not** a closure. That means you need to make a function using `function redirect_user_to_author_page() {` and not `$redirect_user_to_author_page = function () {` (= closure).

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I made the changes but I think the function is not calling. Nothing happens as expected.

Comment: Enable error reporting, you have several syntax errors in there.